# How to change angle range of QML's Dial component?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've been looking for a way how to change QML's `Dial` component's angle range. From [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dial.html) I know it's 140 degrees from "north" to both sides and the [angle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dial.html#angle-prop) property is marked as *read-only*.

I currently have the default 280 degree range. Is there a way to change the range to for example 240 degrees?

[image: 280 degree range dial]

I don't want to write the entire dial myself, the default actually works really well. The purpose of the change is purely aesthetical.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependable on which QuickControls Style (Default, Universal, Fusion e.t.c.) you are using but in all cases, you will need to inject/modify part of the built-in components and create your *hacked* version of Dial

It is very good to know how the dial itself is written, simply finding Default styled Dial on GitHub over [here](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.15.2/src/imports/controls/Dial.qml) This points us to some `DialImpl` component, using Woboq online qt sources, it can be traced [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols2/src/imports/controls/qtquickcontrols2plugin.cpp.html#212) and because `QQuickDefaultDial` is private class, we can't do much with it, therefore you will have to reimplement `DialImpl` yourself and provide your `background` (and possibly also `handle`).

Finally your Dial version can be implemented in this manner

```
// MyDial.qml

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Dial {
    background: Item {
        // Your background definition
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also directly implement your Dial template